# How to put Google Nexus 7 securely in my car for use as sat nav?

Tags: nexus-7, car-dock

I know this question isn't about Android per-se, but about an Android device no less.

I recently got a new Google Nexus 7 tablet.

Now, I'd like to use it as car sat nav, but I couldn't find a decent holder for my car. I'm using a car power strip that also has two USB sockets acting as power outlets for USB devices. Powering the Nexus is no problem, so I don't need a holder/cradle, that supplies power to the tablet.

I was considering building it myself out of a dock or something, but even that I couldn't find. So, how should I put it in my car then? Should I just build myself a car-dock for it?

Comment: I think I've stated my problem: Need to put Nexus 7 FHD in car. I'm not seeking a product advice as such, but at least ideas or solutions to my problem.

Comment: You could put a velcro to its back (and the "other side" of the velcro to the place your N7 should stick in the car). This generic solution would apply to all other devices as well, be it tablets, phones, smart-watches, you-name-it (though fridges might prove a bit heavy for this one).

Comment: @Izzy I actually considered the Velcro idea myself, but it won't work: The tablet is quite large, attaching it to the top of the dashboard is no use, I wouldn't see the screen. Anywhere else, it is covering mostly airbag covers, which could be very dangerous, as it would propel the tablet towards my body with an explosive force...

Comment: Just buy a dock, there are innumerable made for this exact purpose. Most of them have a variable grip so it doesn't matter what tablet you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a mount out of something like [Sugru](http://sugru.com).  Your mount will remain stuck to the dashboard and you would have to make it in such a way that the Nexus would slot into it.

For the elimination of doubt: I don't have any association with Sugru.  I use it to mount my iPhone on the dashboard.

Comment: How did I not know of this stuff... I just ordered some of it. I'll accept if this works out.